# Question on running iPad application

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios4

I would like to know that, is it possible to run iPad application in the start up of iPad device ? also apple approves that kind app?

Please help me out, wherever i search i cant find firm answers.

Thanks for any insights!

Comment: I don't think you can do this.  The only ways I know of to invoke an app are by direct user action (tap) in the springboard, or as a response to a notification.  The iPad-start-up "event" is not part of the app paradigm.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You mean automatically run an app of your choice when a user turns on an iPad?  Like a startup app?

No, that is not possible.  It is only possible to run an app when a user taps on the app icon on the launch screen.